# Fix Json Created with value pair

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode

i have Created below Json , but its not what i want in output please fix inverted quotes in key message and in null

```
    NSString *chID=@"101";
    NSString *reqId=@"REQID";
    NSString *enTypeId=@"100";
    NSString *mb=@"8802034079";


    NSString *MCode=@"21212";
    NSString *RKey=@"QWERTY";
    NSString *OTPCode=@"1414";
    NSString *ORKey=@"ORKEY1212";
    NSString *PinCode=@"null";

    NSDictionary *jsonoutPutDataDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                     chID, @"chID",
                                                     reqId, @"reqId",
                                                     enTypeId, @"enTypeId",
                                                     mb, @"mb",
                                                     nil];


    NSDictionary *jsonDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        jsonoutPutDataDataDictionary, @"outPutData",
                                        MCode, @"MCode",
                                        RKey, @"RKey",
                                        OTPCode, @"OTPCode",
                                        ORKey, @"ORKey",
                                        PinCode, @"PinCode",
                                        nil];



    NSDictionary *jsonmsgDataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           jsonDataDictionary, @"message",
                                           nil];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonmsgDataDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"jsonData as string:\n%@", jsonString);



 NSString *chID=@"101";
    NSString *reqId=@"REQID";
    NSString *enTypeId=@"100";
    NSString *mb=@"8802034079";


    NSString *MCode=@"21212";
    NSString *RKey=@"QWERTY";
    NSString *OTPCode=@"1414";
    NSString *ORKey=@"ORKEY1212";
    NSString *PinCode=@"null";
```

**My OUTPUT :**

```
"message" ={
    "outPutData": {
        "chID": "101",
        "reqId": "REQID",
        "enTypeId": "100",
        "mb": "8802034079"
    },
    "MCode": "21212",
    "RKey": "QWERTY",
    "OTPCode": "1414",
    "ORKey": "ORKEY1212",
    "PinCode": "null"
}
```

**OUTPUT NEEDED:**

```
message ={
    "outPutData": {
        "chID": "101",
        "reqId": "REQID",
        "enTypeId": "100",
        "mb": "8802034079"
    },
    "MCode": "21212",
    "RKey": "QWERTY",
    "OTPCode": "1414",
    "ORKey": "ORKEY1212",
    "PinCode": null
}
```

Comment: You're adding the string "null" instead of a null object, use [NSNull null] instead.

Comment: thnx what about key "message"

Comment: What about it ? I'm pretty sure the quotes have been changed after printed.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem, quotes around keys are fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *PinCode=@"null";
```

Here you are adding the string "null" instead of adding a null object to your dictionary. Instead you should use:

`NSNull *PinCode = [NSNull null];`

The quotes around the keys are correct as they are strings.